# Find range in which each vector element falls in

Tags: r

I have a list of random numbers.

```
x=sample(1:1000, 3)
```

Is there a simple way to get a list of range values in which each element falls in?

```
id=seq(1, 1000, by=50)

 [1]   1  51 101 151 201 251 301 351 401 451 501 551
[13] 601 651 701 751 801 851 901 951
```

eg.

```
x
[1] 637 374  68

distribution
[1] "601~650" "351~400" "51~100"
```

Comment: try `cut(x, breaks = id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this easy solution using `findInterval`:

```
cbind(x,lim_inf=id[findInterval(x,id)],lim_sup=id[findInterval(x,id)+1])
       x lim_inf lim_sup
[1,] 378     351     401
[2,] 609     601     651
[3,] 496     451     501
```